# Google Places API setFields AND getDetails

Tags: google-places-api

The [google places api docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) clearly state: "IMPORTANT: To avoid paying for data that you don't need, be sure to use `Autocomplete.setFields()` to specify only the place data that you will use." But then when I'm calling the `getDetails()` method (see in generic-y form below), I'm specifying my `fields`, which is what `setFields()` sets.

I THINK I'm basically setting them via the `getDetails()` method, but given the caution exercised in the docs, I also don't want to surprise anyone with extra costs besides what we need. I've tried to find a clear answer in the docs, but I haven't found one. I'm hoping someone here knows from experience or has better luck with the docs. Thanks!

```
    const placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(myField);
    placesService.getDetails(
      {
        fields: ['address_components'],
        placeId: result.place_id,
        sessionToken: token,
      },
      details => this.updateMethod(details.address_components),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Autocomplete.setFields` is used when implementing [Places Autocomplete Widget](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#get_place_information) which will constrain the succeeding Places Details request to specific fields only when a user selects a place from the suggestions. Check out the example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform).

However, as for your given sample code, I can see that you are directly using [Places Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details) to get the details of a place given a Place ID and not from the Autocomplete Widget suggestions. With this, you can just set the `fields` in the **`request`** parameter of the [`getDetails(request, callback)`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlacesService.getDetails) method which is what you have correctly done in your code. See this [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details).

Hope this helps!